# Get value of JTextField whose name is stored in a String variable in JAVA

Tags: java

### **Scenario :**

```
public class frame1 extends javax.swing.JFrame { 

 public void processName(){
 String n1 = "txtName";
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"**here i want to show the value from the JTextField using String Variable n1 ,just like we do txtName.getText()**");
 }

 private javax.swing.JTextField txtName;
}
```

---

I know the Question above is weird but the situation which i am in, I must find some other way. please let me know if there's any solution.
Thanks.

**NOTE :** I pasted only the relevant code above. Please assume that I call processName() function on a Button click event.

**EDIT :** 
The Exact Problem is : I have a list of JTextFields that have exactly same name as Database fields.
Now I want to populate those JTextFields with data from the database using a while loop. And they are many. So I don't want to change the JTextfield names or Database field names.

Comment: I couled suggest to use either a map or reflection, but since this sounds like an [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you should probably tell us what problem you like to fix with this approach.

Comment: @Tom is right, what prevents you from calling the textfield directly ?

Comment: @Tom Please see my edited questions.Thanks.

Comment: @Berger Please see my edited questions.Thanks.

Comment: If you had shared small minimal executable code, we would have given our best effort to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Jonathan's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17806100/6392662 has helped me to solve my issue.